# Keep getting the same error using Scanner in java - Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException:

Tags: java

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name = sc.nextLine();
      String[] words = name.split(" ");
      String firstName = words[0];
      String middleName = words[1];
      if (words.length == 2) {
         System.out.println(middleName + ", " + firstName.charAt(0) + ".");
         }
         else {
            String lastName = words[2];
            System.out.println(lastName + ", " + firstName.charAt(0) + "." + middleName.charAt(0) + ".");
         }
   }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:6)
```

This happens to me almost every time I use scanner.

Comment: What inputs are you giving it?

Comment: Are you running your code from your IDE?

Comment: _This happens to me almost every time I use scanner_ Does that mean that sometimes you **don't** get an error?